# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was developing apps using web services when I run the application it got responses but some time its crashes and show error like this:

> NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'

Here is my coding:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/tennis/news/headlines?apikey=th98vzm67pufc36ka42xxxmy"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

NSError *err;
NSURLResponse *response;

NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
NSDictionary *jsonArray=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData  options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];
NSArray *headlinetop=[jsonArray objectForKey:@"headlines"];

for (int i=0; i<[headlinetop count]; i++)
{
    NSString *headstr=[[headlinetop objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"headline"];
    [loadingcell addObject:headstr];
}
```

Comment: And what about logging `responseData`, `err`...? Is data nil for only one URL?

Comment: i got response well but some time it crashes like this

Comment: Well, when it crash, checking the `err` could be interesting. And I'd use a other `NSError` than using twice `err`. Not checking them, is like putting `nil` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the `"headline"` object isn't always available; guard against that using:

```
for (int i=0; i<[headlinetop count]; i++)
{
    NSString *headstr=[[headlinetop objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"headline"];
    if (headstr)
        [loadingcell addObject:headstr];
}
```

If `loadcell` is an Objective-C collection class, it will object to `headstr` being `nil` as they cannot store NULL objects.

Comment: loading cell is the mutable array

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this code:

```
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
NSDictionary *jsonArray=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData  options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];
```

Sending a URL request you should always expect that something went wrong. There are many reasons for it. In this case `responseData` is `nil`. `NSJSONSerialization` expects the `data` arg not to be `nil`: Error.

When receiving a response for a request you should always check it for being `nil`. Always.

So the code should look like this:

```
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
if (responseData == nil)
{
  //  Maybe logging. But getting nil as a response of a URL request isn't exciting.
  return; // or whatever you have to (not) do
}
NSDictionary *jsonArray=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData  options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is Url which you are using.
Please check the following link:
['NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603708/nsinvalidargumentexception-reason-data-parameter-is-nil)